# Cannot mount/format/modify NVMe drive

Tags: partitioning, encryption, nvme

I have this Intel NVMe on a laptop that previously had a Windows installation and was encrypted using an encryption tool. One day it decided that it won't boot to Windows anymore and I decided to just proceed to wipe clean the drive.

However it wouldn't let me delete the partitions on the Windows installation setup. It would throw a `We couldn't create a new partition 0xa2c1d300` error when I try.

When using `diskpart` to `clean` the whole drive, error `Incorrect function.` appears.

This is what happens when I try to modify the drive thru GParted.

[image]

I know the NVMe drive isn't defective because the laptop is fairly new and the built-in diagnostics show that the drive is okay by passing all the tests. So I am kinda stuck at this point.

If all else fails warranty is my last resort but hoping I could fix it now so I can get into speed.

Appreciate all the feedback!

Comment: Your question is unclear as regarding if you have one disk or more. If only one, which disk encryption tool have you used?

Comment: If it "suddenly wouldn't boot" then there is a good possibility that the drive flash storage has failed somehow. "Passing all the tests" doesn't mean it actually tried to write or even read from the drive itself.